# API endpoint - Require multi-factor authentication (MFA) for all direct UI logins to your Salesforce org

Tags: rest-api, security

I didn't find any, maybe you can help.
I am looking for the API endpoint of Session Settings -> Require multi-factor authentication (MFA) for all direct UI logins to your Salesforce org.

I found the following documentation: [SecuritySettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_securitysettings.htm) -> `EnableMFADirectUILoginOptIn`, but when I send an API request I don't get this key.

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone?
Would like to use the API for the following setting:
[Enable MFA for Your Entire Org](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_mfa_org_wide_setting.htm&type=5)